# ZLib C# inflate socket data

Tags: c#, sockets, .net-2.0, zlib

I'm trying to parse messages sent from a server that's compressed using zlib, but I'm not sure how to do so with C#'s implementation of async sockets. I'm using Microsoft's example for async client socket.

https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx

I'm guessing the correct place to do the inflation is here:

```
private static void ReceiveCallback( IAsyncResult ar ) {
   ....
   string bufferedString = Encoding.ASCII.GetString(state.buffer,0,bytesRead);
   ....
}
```

I've tried passing state.buffer as the input parameter to the following function along with bytesRead as the length, but this results in a System.IO.IOException: Corrupted data ReadInternal exception.

```
public static string UnZip(byte[] byteArray, int length)
{   
    //Prepare for decompress
    System.IO.MemoryStream ms = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);
    System.IO.Compression.GZipStream sr = new System.IO.Compression.GZipStream(ms,
                                                                               System.IO.Compression.CompressionMode.Decompress);

    //Reset variable to collect uncompressed result
    byteArray = new byte[length];

    //Decompress
    int rByte = sr.Read(byteArray, 0, byteArray.Length);

    //Transform byte[] unzip data to string
    System.Text.StringBuilder sB = new System.Text.StringBuilder(rByte);
    //Read the number of bytes GZipStream red and do not a for each bytes in
    //resultByteArray;
    for (int i = 0; i < rByte; i++)
    {
        sB.Append((char)byteArray[i]);
    }
    sr.Close();
    ms.Close();
    sr.Dispose();
    ms.Dispose();
    return sB.ToString();
}
```

How can I inflate the contents of state.buffer?

Comment: "How can I inflate the contents of state.buffer?" So you're essentially asking how to implement zlib decompression in C#?

Comment: If it helps, this is a compression example, but should be straightforward to instead decompress with same library: http://stackoverflow.com/a/1327688/84206

Comment: @AaronLS I've tried a variety of implementations of inflate/unzip, including DotNetZip, but passing state.buffer as the input always results in an exception (details in the above edit). I presume this is because state.buffer functions differently than a standard byte[].

Comment: @JimmyXu Is there a reason that you're using Asynchronous Programming Model (APM with BeginXXX and EndXXX pairs) instead of the newer TPL and async/await? Life gets *a lot* easier with async/await.

Comment: @spender i'm fairly new to C# and this is the first I've come across TPL. I'll look for resources, but in the meantime, do you have any suggestions for examples of async sockets in TPL? Thanks

Comment: If you're passing `state.buffer` to `UnZip(byte[] byteArray, int length)` then one problem will be `state.buffer` will only be a portion of the stream(just the first part that was read), while UnZip is designed to operate on the entire file.  UnZip needs to be adapted to a buffered approach, or a dirtier approach is to repeatedly read using BeginReceive accumulating buffers into a byte array/memory stream of the entire file then use your UnZip function to deflate.

Comment: ReceiveCallback repeatedly calls itself through AsyncCallback, because each state.buffer is another chunk of the input, and the way it accumulates results is to append them to the `ar.AsyncState.sb` string buffer(you might instead accumulate into a memorystream): https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bew39x2a(v=vs.110).aspx