# Compression and decompression problem with zlib.Net

Tags: c#, .net, zlib

I am using [ZLIB.Net](http://www.componentace.com/zlib_.NET.htm) and I just don't understand what should I do to compress a stream which is not `FileStream`, but `MemoryStream`. By doing:

```
byte[] buffer = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes("Hello World");

MemoryStream outStream = new MemoryStream();
zlib.ZOutputStream outZStream = new zlib.ZOutputStream(
    outStream,
    zlib.zlibConst.Z_BEST_COMPRESSION);

outZStream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
outZStream.finish();

buffer = outStream.GetBuffer();
Debug.WriteLine(DateTime.Now.ToString() + ":" + buffer.Length);

MemoryStream inStream = new MemoryStream(buffer);
MemoryStream mo = new MemoryStream();
zlib.ZInputStream inZStream = new zlib.ZInputStream(
    inStream,
    zlib.zlibConst.Z_BEST_COMPRESSION);

int n = 0;
while ((n = inZStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length)) > 0)
{
    mo.Write(buffer, 0, n);
}

string STR = ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetString(mo.GetBuffer());
```

I can't get the string `"Hello World"` back.

Comment: What do you get instead of "Hello worlds"?

Comment: It seems you misuse zlib. ZInputStream should be in the first place while ZOutputStream should be in the second place. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/737258/zlib-from-c-to-chow-to-convert-byte-to-stream-and-stream-to-byte

Comment: I'm getting just something: x??H???W?/?I

Comment: As you can see there are H and W... at least it means I'm not misused.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Thanks to user [@longbkit](https://stackoverflow.com/users/569425/longbkit) for the reference to [the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/3844239) (itself by [@JoshStribling](https://stackoverflow.com/users/464386/josh-stribling)) that helped me figure this out.

```c#
public static void CompressData(byte[] inData, out byte[] outData)
{
    using (MemoryStream outMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (ZOutputStream outZStream = new ZOutputStream(outMemoryStream, zlibConst.Z_DEFAULT_COMPRESSION))
    using (Stream inMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(inData))
    {
        CopyStream(inMemoryStream, outZStream);
        outZStream.Finish();
        outData = outMemoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}

public static void DecompressData(byte[] inData, out byte[] outData)
{
    using (MemoryStream outMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (ZOutputStream outZStream = new ZOutputStream(outMemoryStream))
    using (Stream inMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(inData))
    {
        CopyStream(inMemoryStream, outZStream);
        outZStream.Finish();
        outData = outMemoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}

public static void CopyStream(System.IO.Stream input, System.IO.Stream output)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2000];
    int len;
    while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, 2000)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    output.Flush();
}
```

It works.
But what I see is the only difference between Compression and Decompression is Compression Type in ZOutput Constructor...

Amazing. For me would be more clear if Compression is called Output while Decompression - Input. or such... in fact it's Output only.

Comment: If you're using .Net 4.0 you can simply use the built-in [`Stream.CopyTo`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.stream.copyto.aspx).

Comment: Can't use Stream.CopyTo for this example or you will get an ObjectDisposedException on the output stream.

Comment: I have the same doubt. I thought ZOutputStream is to generate compressed output, and ZInputStream was to read compressed input and generate decompressed output. But now I see that I was wrong. Both compress and decompress are to be done with ZOutputStream. So then what is ZInputStream used for?

Comment: It's true that `CopyTo()` doesn't seem to work, however, this is due to some possible bug in `ZOutputStream` not providing correct `CanWrite` and `CanRead` values. If you just subclass `ZOutputStream` and do nothing else but override those two to return *true*, `CopyTo()` will work just fine.

Comment: in case `outZStream.finish()` doesn't give correct encoding, you should use `outZStream.FlushMode = zlibConst.Z_SYNC_FLUSH` before CopyStream and don't call finish

Answer (score 1):

Change code.

```
inZStream.Read
```

->
    inZStream.read

from sourceCode in ZInputStream.cs