# (Windows Phone 10)Decompress data by zlib

Tags: uwp, windows-10-mobile

I am developing windows phone 10 application, I have to compress data to upload to server and other client will download and decompress it.

For compress data I have implemented follow this link : [Compression and decompression problem with zlib.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6620655/compression-and-decompression-problem-with-zlib-net)

Here is my code :

```
       public static void CompressData(byte[] inData, out byte[] outData)
    {
        using (MemoryStream outMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
        using (ZOutputStream outZStream = new ZOutputStream(outMemoryStream, 9))
        using (Stream inMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(inData))
        {
            CopyStream(inMemoryStream, outZStream);
            outZStream.Finish();
            outData = outMemoryStream.ToArray();
        }
    }
```

But when I decompress data, It is always go to exception ( Exeption is : Message = "inflating: "), Here is my decompress function :

```
public static void DecompressData(byte[] inData, out byte[] outData)
    {
        try
        {
            using (MemoryStream outMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
            using (ZOutputStream outZStream = new ZOutputStream(outMemoryStream))
            using (Stream inMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(inData))
            {
                CopyStream(inMemoryStream, outZStream);
                outZStream.Finish();
                outData = outMemoryStream.ToArray();
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            outData = null;
        }

    }
```

Anyone can help me show something wrong in my decompress function? I am using nuget packet WinRTBouncyCastle .