# C# - how to decompress an ISO-8859-1 string

Tags: c#, compression, iso-8859-1

I have C# program that received zipped bitstream received in iso-8859-1 character set.
I need to get the string that was compressed.
It should be equivalent to the this python code:

```
zlib.decompress(bytes(bytearray(json_string, 'iso8859')), 15+32).
```

I tried this code for decompress:

```
        Encoding iso_8859_1 = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
        byte[] isoBytes = iso_8859_1.GetBytes(inputString);

        // then do GZip extract
        MemoryStream objMemStream = new MemoryStream();
        objMemStream.Write(isoBytes, 0, isoBytes.Length);
        objMemStream.Seek(0, SeekOrigin.Begin);

        GZipStream objDecompress = new GZipStream(objMemStream, CompressionMode.Decompress);
```

But, objDecompress.Read failed, so I did something wrong.

***** Edit 31/03

The Java code which do the compression is:

```
    ByteArrayOutputStream out = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
    GZIPOutputStream gzip = new GZIPOutputStream(out);
    gzip.write(JsonStr.getBytes());
    gzip.close();
    return out.toString("ISO-8859-1");
```

I need a C# code to get the JsonStr.
Would like to get some help.

Comment: Are you sure you don't want to decompress first, then interpret those bytes as ISO-5589-1?

Comment: @madreflection looks like python code indeed takes string and converts it into array and only then decompresses. I agree that it makes very little sense... but that what code tells us. AZur - could you please [edit] post with an example value (confusingly called `json_string` in Python example as it clearly can't be JSON). Also did you looked up what `15+32` stands for?

Comment: It is actually 47. [Doc here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/zlib.html): +40 to +47 = 32 + (8 to 15): Uses the low 4 bits of the value as the window size logarithm, and automatically accepts either the zlib or gzip format. According to the documentation, this value determines the window size, thus increasing the compression efficiency.

Comment: Don't you want to Decompress the GZIP first before applying encoding?  A GZIP contains ASCII characters only and no encoding is needed.

Answer (score 3):

There are build in [`DeflateStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.deflatestream) [`GZipStream`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.compression.gzipstream) classes, but I couldn't manage to reverse this probably because [`ZLibNative`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/parent/parent/parent/InternalApis/NDP_FX/inc/ZLibNative.cs) has default constants like [`public const int Deflate_DefaultWindowBits = -15`](https://referencesource.microsoft.com/#system/parent/parent/parent/InternalApis/NDP_FX/inc/ZLibNative.cs,208). There are discussions on this subject like in this DotNet runtime issue ["System.IO.Compression to support zlib thin wrapper over DEFLATE?"](https://github.com/dotnet/runtime/issues/16923)

There is [`zlib.net`](https://www.nuget.org/packages/zlib.net/) NuGet package which you can use to decompress the data. You can read of a simple compress/decompress implementation here [Compression and decompression problem with zlib.Net](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6627194/1889685).

#### Python compress

```py
import zlib
import binascii

json_string = '{"aaaaaaaaaa": 1111111111, "bbbbbbbbbbb": "cccccccccccc"}'

compressed_data = zlib.compress(bytes(bytearray(json_string, 'iso8859')), 2)
decompressed_data = zlib.decompress(compressed_data, 15+32)

print('Compressed HEX data: %s' % (binascii.hexlify(compressed_data)))
print('Decompressed data: %s' % (decompressed_data))
```

Will output:

```sh
Compressed HEX data: b'785eab564a8403252b054338d051504a4200a09452321250aa0500e4681153'
Decompressed data: b'{"aaaaaaaaaa": 1111111111, "bbbbbbbbbbb": "cccccccccccc"}'
```

#### C# decompress

```cs
static void Main(string[] args) {
    var extCompressedHex = "785eab564a8403252b054338d051504a4200a09452321250aa0500e4681153";
    var extCompressed = HexStringToByteArray(extCompressedHex);

    byte[] extDecompressedData;
    DecompressData(extCompressed, out extDecompressedData);

    string extDecompressedJson = Encoding.GetEncoding("ISO-8859-1").GetString(extDecompressedData);

    Console.WriteLine("Hex ext compressed: {0}", ByteArrayToHex(extCompressed.ToArray()));
    Console.WriteLine("Raw ext decompressed: {0}", extDecompressedJson);
}


void DecompressData(byte[] inData, out byte[] outData)
{
    using (MemoryStream outMemoryStream = new MemoryStream())
    using (ZOutputStream outZStream = new ZOutputStream(outMemoryStream))
    using (Stream inMemoryStream = new MemoryStream(inData))
    {
        CopyStream(inMemoryStream, outZStream);
        outZStream.finish();
        outData = outMemoryStream.ToArray();
    }
}

// Helper functions ___________________________________________________

string ByteArrayToHex(byte[] bytes)
{
    StringBuilder sw = new StringBuilder();

    foreach (byte b in bytes)
    {
        sw.AppendFormat("{0:x2}", b);
    }

    return sw.ToString();
}

void CopyStream(System.IO.Stream input, System.IO.Stream output)
{
    byte[] buffer = new byte[2000];
    int len;
    while ((len = input.Read(buffer, 0, 2000)) > 0)
    {
        output.Write(buffer, 0, len);
    }
    output.Flush();
}

byte[] HexStringToByteArray(string hex)
{
    return Enumerable.Range(0, hex.Length)
                     .Where(x => x % 2 == 0)
                     .Select(x => Convert.ToByte(hex.Substring(x, 2), 16))
                     .ToArray();
}
```

Will output:

```sh
Hex ext compressed: 785eab564a8403252b054338d051504a4200a09452321250aa0500e4681153
Raw ext decompressed: {"aaaaaaaaaa": 1111111111, "bbbbbbbbbbb": "cccccccccccc"}
```

You can check it working in this [.NET Fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/SY0mMi).

Answer (score 1):

I think that it should by more like this.

```
Encoding iso_8859_1 = Encoding.GetEncoding("iso-8859-1");
string inputData = "";
string outputData = "";

// then do GZip extract
using (MemoryStream uncompressedData = new MemoryStream())
using (GZipStream decompressor = new GZipStream(uncompressedData, CompressionMode.Decompress))
{
    byte[] inData = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(inputData);
    decompressor.Write(inData, 0, inData.Length);
    outputData = iso_8859_1.GetString(uncompressedData.ToArray());
}
```